# Fetch data from 2 tables without relationship in doctrine

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony2. It suggested to use doctrine so I'm learning it.

Now I am testing to fetch data from 2 tables. Suppose table names are `tb_info` & `tb_group`. I've 2 classes with same name with proper ORM that represents these 2 tables.

In simple query, we do

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_info,tb_group"
```

And all the magical data come to my hand. Now with **Doctrine** I can't find simple way like this. I tried

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p
    FROM AcmeDbBundle:tb_info,AcmeDbBundle:tb_group p'
);
```

This doesn't work. I saw some ways to collect data from 2 different tables. **But I don't want to use relationship.**

Is there any simple ways to write query in doctrine to fetch data from multiple tables?? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Why would you do that? That doesn't seem logical. Tables have different structures and different informations. Why not just run two queries?

Comment: @Touki You don't need to bother about that bro. There are thousands of situations where I can need that. Suppose in tb_info there is a student's id,name,roll and in tb_group there is id and bloodGroup. I need total data of that student with 1 query. Now I want that using doctrine.

Comment: Ok, if it doesn't bother you, you can just use `$em->getConnection()->query($nativeSQL);` to run a native query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Doctrine QueryBuilder in a repository function:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();       
    $queryBuilder->addSelect("position,candidate")
        ->from("RadsphereRecruitmentBundle:Position", 'position')
        ->from("RadsphereRecruitmentBundle:Candidate", 'candidate')
        ->andWhere("position.open = :open")
        ->setParameter("open",true);

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: More than one from in the QueryBuilder, who would've thunk it was that easy?

Comment: @Aaron not me, I was just looking for a solution and it was sooo simple... double 'from' FTW!